# How to start jasmine tests with grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, requirejs, jasmine

I want to create a grunt task for running jasmine tests automatically when the code changed. For AMD support I installed [grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs](https://github.com/cloudchen/grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs). I added these lines to my gruntfile:

```
connect: {
    test : {
        port : 8000
    }
},

jasmine: {
    jasmine_tests: {
        src: 'src/**/*.js',
        options: {
            specs: 'spec/*Spec.js',
            helpers: 'spec/*Helper.js',
            host: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
            template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
            templateOptions: {
                requireConfigFile: 'public/js/app/config/config.js'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Now I try to start my tests by typing `grunt jasmine`. But all I get is this:

> Running "jasmine:jasmine_tests" (jasmine) task
>
> Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS
>
> Warning: PhantomJS failed to load your page. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

What could be wrong there?

My directory structure:

```
- website3
    - .grunt
        + grunt-contrib-jasmine
    + node_modules
    - public
        - js
            - app
                + collections
                - config
                    > config.js
                + ...
                - views
                    + ...
                    > AddVehicleView.js
                    > ...
        + libs
        > index.html
    + server
    - spec
        + helpers
        - support
            > jasmine.json
        > AddVehicleViewSpec.js
    > .bowerrc
    > ...
    > _SpecRunner.html
    > Gruntfile.js
    > package.json
```

Comment: Is `127.0.0.1:8000` available via http? How do you serve the files? With `connect`? Execute your tests with `--debug` to get more information.

Comment: And for watching files for change take a look at `grunt-contrib-watch`

Comment: i added the connect lines in my question. what else do I have to do, for providing the files to test at the given port?

Comment: is it necessary to receive the tested data via ip?

Comment: If you want to execute your tests in browsers, you have to serve them via HTTP. If they are just for node.js/io.js, you don't need that. In your connect config you only specify a port, no files to serve. Have a look at the documentation: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect And after all you have to create a task that executes connect AND jasmine: `grunt.registerTask('test', ['connect', 'jasmine'])` and execute it by `grunt test`

Comment: ok thanks, that helps me a lot, but i still don't really know, what is the solution I need. I have requirejs modules, that I want to load and then test them. i think they should be able to run in browsers as well as node.js. i tried not to use connect and specified `options.src: 'public/js/**'`. the tests are being run, but it says `Illegal path or script error` I think I have to provide the path differently but how? I did this in `beforeAll()`: `requirejs(['../public/js/app/views/AddVehicleView'], function(View){
            view = new View();
            done();
        });`

Comment: could you post your project directory structure?

Comment: I added the directory structure in my question...

Answer (score 1):

you have to do `grunt connect` to serve your files first and then in another terminal tab do `grunt jasmine` , that's all.